# 3D Real Time Mapping

Tags: mapping, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm looking for some advice on how I can build a 3D map in real time using an Asus Xtion (or Kinect). I have tried RTABMAP and had some success, however when I get into an environment that has very few visual clues I run into trouble. So I'm kind of at a bit of a dead end at the moment so any advice on where to look or other packages to look at would be great appreciated.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182402/3d-real-time-mapping/) by [sxp](https://answers.ros.org/users/10651/sxp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-07-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a blog post last year discussing some of the 3d mapping packages released into ROS: http://www.showusyoursensors.com/2013/02/3d-mapping-is-here.html

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sxp](https://answers.ros.org/users/10651/sxp/) on 2014-07-03**:
Hi Fergs, thanks for your response. Sadly I've tried all the packages you mention in that post and none of them quite do what I'm after. It seems to me thats theres been no development since then!